# Recurly JS strips session data on post

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, csrf

I'm setting up Recurly JS on my rails app.  To access the current_order or current_user I store their ids within the session.  However, when Recurly JS is posting to my 'success' path, all this data is getting stripped out of my session.  I can manually make sure this data is there by doing this:

```
update_checkout_url("payment", :order_id => session[:order_id], :user_id => current_user.id)
```

But this doesn't seem very railsy.  Is this some sort of csrf issue? Or is it just not possible to keep this data persistent when posting to recurly?

Comment: I went with my current implementation above.  On the receiving end, I reset my session needs.  Not a terrible approach, but I don't think I have any other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem and with the help of the recuryly google group, I found that it was a csrf thing with rails protection. I added the following to my controller and specified the action.

protect_from_forgery :except => :successful

This took care of the problem. Hopefull this will help someone else.